# Excel, See if Sheet A is referenced elsewhere in Workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a fairly large workbook. Is there a way to check if a certain sheet is referenced by any other sheets ie via formulas?

For example I have a large dataset in Sheet A, but all the other sheets in my workbook may have some sumifs, vlookups, index match,  etc applied referencing sheet A.

I've heard of trace dependents but not sure if it works for entire sheets/ give desired results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Find function:

1. CTRL+F
2. Click `Options >>`
3. Within: Workbook
4. Look in: Formulas
5. Find What: `Type your sheetname here`

You can use "Find Next" to look at them one at a time or press "Find All" to get a list of all places at once.

Comment: Please note that this does NOT work if you have defined names somewhere on the worksheet. The Find function will only detect direct references to cells or ranges on the worksheet, not to cells or ranges that you have given a name. This you have to check separately in the Name Manager.